# Django models in admin return TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I'm working on a project using Django(3) and Python(3) in which I have added few models and added those models in `admin.py`, but when I open the admin panel and try to add an object for those models it returns an error.

Here's one of my model which is returning error:

**From `models.py`:**

```
class CurrencyManagementAssetsModel(models.Model):
    RequestId = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    CbnInstitutionCode = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False)
    SortCode = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    Count = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    AssetClassificationId = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    AssetTypeId = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    ValueOfCurrencyDistributed = models.DecimalField(max_digits='20', decimal_places='10', 
    blank=False)
    VaultCapacity = models.DecimalField(max_digits='20', decimal_places='10', blank=False)
    Year = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    HalfOftheYear = models.IntegerField(blank=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Currency Management Assets'
```

**From `admin.py`:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CurrencyManagementAssetsModel

admin.site.register(CurrencyManagementAssetsModel)
```

and Here's the error I'm getting when click on that particular model in admin:

> Request Method:   GET
> Request  URL:     http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/reports/currencymanagementassetsmodel/
> Django Version:   3.1.3
> Exception Type:   TypeError
> Exception Value:   bad operand type for unary -: 'str'

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Can you show us the code for `try to add an object`? The error looks like you are trying to apply negative sign (unary `-`) to a string instead of a number!

Comment: since you are getting an error when trying to work with the admin, it could also be that the problem lies in the `admin.py` that defines the admin for this model

Comment: @abdul Rehman, Please share the `admin.py`  file.

Comment: @IqbalHussain added `admin.py`

Answer (score 1):

reason of the error

```
decimal_places='10'
max_digits='20'
```

it should be

```
decimal_places=10
max_digits=20
```

Answer (score 0):

Django automatically inserts null values to fields which have   `blank =True`. So to correct your error specify `null=True` in that field since the field is integer  field instead of char field.   please sorry I made a mistake, please remove blank = false from your models fields because the blank PARAM is false by default.

Comment: But my `model` doesn't have any field with `blank=True`